# Raspberry Pi 4 に VNC を使って Windows から接続したいが「No route to host is known」となって繋がらない

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc

使用しているもの

・Raspberry Pi 4
・Windows 10 搭載ノートPC
・VNC Viewer

今回発生している問題は有線でのVNCでWindowsにデスクトップを表示させたいのですが、正しいIPアドレスを入力しても「No route to host is known」と表示され接続できません。
Wi-Fiを使用した接続ではIPアドレスを使用して接続できることは確認しています。
自分以外のRaspberry Piでも有線接続ができていません。

今回発生した理由がわからないのは、1か月前までは問題なく有線での接続ができていました。
しかしRaspberry Piのファームウェアに問題が発生し、更新をかけたところ今回の問題が発生しました。

Comment: 接続方式 (有線 or 無線) はあまり重要じゃなく、あくまで RasPi と Windows とがネットワーク的に繋がっているのかをまず確認してみてください。

Comment: ↑上記のことを確認する方法はありますか？

Comment: RPI の IP アドレスを DHCP で配布している（そのためにはいわゆる家庭用ルータが必要）か、手で固定 IP アドレスを振っているかとか。エラーメッセージ `no route` ってことはネットワーク部が違うとか。調べるポイントはいっぱいありすぎて簡単に説明できないっス。

Comment: プライベートIPアドレスならば, それらのノードの IPアドレスを[質問に追記](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/96183/edit)してみてはどうでしょう